# Employment contract prohibiting salary discussion in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

I work for a company in the UK and my employment contract states that I must not discuss my salary with colleagues. I know that this is illegal in the USA but cant find any information about in the UK

Are there any laws in the UK that relate to this??

Answer (score 4):

http://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/experts/article-1698485/Can-I-discuss-my-pay-with-colleagues.html

In short, there are no laws prohibiting or rendering such contract clauses unenforceable, but an employer cannot rely on such a contractual clause to abrogate its obligations under the Equality Act 2010.